# How to import constants in a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jspinclude

Are there any better ways to use constants in a JSP than:

```
<%@ page import="static package.Interface.NAME"%>
```

Is there any downside to using these (outside of mixing code/content)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Create a bean with getters that expose constants and set in an HttpRequest in `<filter>`.

Then you can use JSTL to get to these constants.

You nailed the downside of the original approach.

Comment: Since **constants** are applicationwide, I'd just put it once in application scope during webapp's startup using a `ServletContextListener` or whatever application hook the MVC framework in question provides, if any used.

Comment: @BalusC: This is even better idea.